# How to open the fbSession in ios?

Tags: ios, facebook, session

i am trying to open the session like this, but it returns accesstoken null.

```
   NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"basic_info",@"email", nil];

            [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                               allowLoginUI:YES
                                          completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                              FBSessionState status,
                                                              NSError *error) {


    NSString * accessToken = [[[FBSession activeSession] accessTokenData] accessToken];
                                              NSLog(@"stringtoken%@",accessToken);
    if([accessToken isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
        {
        }
```

what is wrong with my code and what should i do? thanx in advance.

Comment: check out accepted answer in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921269/fbsession-activesession-isopen-returns-no-even-though-the-user-logged-in

Comment: before posting this question i had a look on that question but that doesn't help in my case