# Facebook SDK: AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken always null, even after logging in

Tags: ios, xamarin, facebook-access-token, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am using the following code (on Xamarin) to log in using the latest Facebook SDK (I am also using Parse to manage my backend):

```
partial void LoginWithFacebook (UIButton sender)
        {
            LoginManager login = new LoginManager();
            login.LogInWithReadPermissionsAsync(kPermissions).ContinueWith(t => {
                if (t.IsFaulted && t.Exception != null) {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine("Error while authenticating: {0}", t.Exception.Message);
                } else {
                    var result = t.Result;
                    if (result.IsCancelled) {
                        Console.Error.WriteLine("User canceled the operation");
                    } else {
                        Console.WriteLine("Authenticated!");

                        ParseFacebookUtils.LogInAsync(result.Token.UserID, result.Token.TokenString, (DateTime)result.Token.ExpirationDate).ContinueWith(loginTask => {
                            if (!loginTask.IsFaulted) {
                                InvokeOnMainThread(() => PerformSegue("GoToDashboard", null));
                            } else {
                                Console.Error.WriteLine("Could not login to Parse");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

And then, to load the friends list (who are also using the App) I use the following code:

```
if (AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken != null) {
                var request = new GraphRequest ("me/friends", null);
                request.Start (new GraphRequestHandler ((connection, result, error) => {
                    if (error != null) {
                        Console.Error.WriteLine("Error fetching the friends list");
                    } else {
                        Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", result);
                    }

                    hud.Hide(true);
                }));
            }
```

But the AccessToken always seem to be null even if the authentication is successful. I tried setting it by hand after the authentication but when the App restarts, it is lost again.

**EDIT**

I have removed the condition "if (AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken != null)" and it makes the request with no problems so I guess I am just using the wrong way to detect if the user is logged in. What's the correct way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921269/fbsession-activesession-isopen-returns-no-even-though-the-user-logged-in

Comment: Check this post- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30205396/fbsdkaccesstoken-currentaccesstoken-is-not-being-updated-after-log-in/30206661#30206661

Comment: @sasquatch There is no "FBSession" class in the new SDK

Comment: @VijayMasiwal my problem is that the "AccessToken.CurrentTokenAccess" is always null (I check it after being successfully authenticated, in a different UIViewController) while the user in the question you referenced just checked the property at the wrong time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the question referenced by @VijayMasiwal I was able to discover the problem. I had forgot to initialize Facebook in the App Delegate.

Here is how the FinishedLaunching method should be implemented when using Facebook:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{
    Settings.AppID = kFacebookAppID;
    Settings.DisplayName = kFacebookDisplayName;

    // I had forgotten this line :)
    return ApplicationDelegate.SharedInstance.FinishedLaunching (application, launchOptions);
}
```

Hope that helps.