# How to know user has already done Facebook login at iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am developing iOS App which use Facebook iOS SDK 4.

When user has already done Facebook login, by doing Facebook login the dialog which shows "user has already approved your app" had be displayed.
So, do not show the dialog. I want to know whether the user has already done Facebook login.
Anyone know the good way? I think accessToken is returned if user once had done Facebook login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FBSDKAccessToken` manage current logged user's accessToken.
According to official [Facebook Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios) guide
"`FBSDKAccessToken` Represents the access token provided by a successful login. Most important, it provides a global +currentAccessToken to represent the currently logged in user."

The `currentAccessToken` is a convenient representation of the token of the current user and is used by other SDK components (like `FBSDKLoginManager`).

According to above you can check either user has valid accessToken or not and based on this you can track call login method otherwise just skip to next flow.

Answer (score 0):

In Facebook the access tokens are per user so you can pass them around apps and they will work. In your case if you can ship an access token from another app you will be able to skip the next logging in and use the API normally.

However I think this [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921269/fbsession-activesession-isopen-returns-no-even-though-the-user-logged-in) will help you.

Things are a little bit different with iOS cause I have done a facebook login on Android and got no such issues.